# How to remove all special character and replace only one white space in PHP?

Tags: php, regex

I've used PHP function to remove all special characters and will replace with only one white space ( ) but below function will replace all character than replaced to all that characters with a space.
**Example:** My string = `hello-friend--how() are---` 
**Result:** string = `helllo friend  how  are   .`
So it is not a thing that i want.

Here is my function

```
public function remove_sp_char($str) {

    return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]/', ' ', $str);// !\s+!
}
```

Thanks for help us

Comment: Perhaps, [`[^A-Za-z0-9]+`](https://regex101.com/r/kB4pM0/1)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

replace every special character to a space,

```
preg_replace('/\W/', ' ', $str);
```

replace adjacent special characters to a space,

```
preg_replace('/\W+/', ' ', $str);
```

Comment: Your will work is I used like this 

public function remove_sp_char($str) {
        return preg_replace('/[\W]+/', ' ', $str);// !\s+!
    }

Comment: @Cambodiachannel this wont replace `-`

Answer (score 2):

```
return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]+/', ' ', $str);

                                    ^^
```

Use `+` to match more than `1` special characters and replace by

Comment: Are you sure it is working as expected? Have a look at [the result](https://regex101.com/r/qN6hV6/1): `hello-friend--how are---`.

Comment: @Stribizhev

Here is that function and it work as well

    public function remove_sp_char($str) {
        return preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\-]+/', ' ', $str);// !\s+!
    }

Comment: vks has pointed out the root cause of the issue, but the requirements are unclear then.

Comment: Do you see I write all special charactre?